# Hiding step in a business flow

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to get a handle of a step to (hopefully) hide it/show it from the stage.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var steps = Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveStage().getSteps();
```

I feel like I'm close, I can see in the console that they are there. But `steps.getByName()` returns null on all of them, that I know are there.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not done through manipulating the step objects, but rather a simple way through the `Xrm.Page` client side reference

As such:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('header_process_fieldName').setVisible(false);
```

Reference: http://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/07/how-to-apply-script-on-header-fields-and-bpf-fields/